How do I upload multiple documents via Minimal API endpoint?
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core project where I need to store multiple KYC documents for a legal entity in an Azure Storage Account Container.
Questions:

How do I actually upload these documents? IFormFileCollection in some way?
Are DocumentType, DocumentName, DocumentDescription, and DocumentUrl enough for Azure Storage Account, or have I missed any other property that's required?

Payload Example
{
  "legalEntity": {
    "name": "Acme Corporation",
    "shortName": "Acme Corp",
    "type": "Organization",
    "registrationNumber": "REG123456",
    "dateOfIncorporation": "2000-01-01T00:00:00",
    "country": "United States",
    "taxIdentificationNumber": "TAX987654",
    "industryType": "Technology",
    "contactInformation": {
      "primaryContactName": "John Doe",
      "primaryContactPhoneNumber": "+1 (555) 123-4567",
      "primaryContactEmail": "john.doe@acmecorp.com",
      "secondaryContactName": "Jane Smith",
      "secondaryContactPhoneNumber": "+1 (555) 987-6543",
      "secondaryContactEmail": "jane.smith@acmecorp.com",
      "website": "https://www.acmecorp.com"
    },
    "addressInformation": {
      "streetAddress": "123 Tech Street",
      "city": "Silicon Valley",
      "stateProvince": "CA",
      "postalCode": "94000",
      "country": "United States"
    },
    "bankInformation": {
      "accountName": "Acme Corporation Operating Account",
      "bankName": "Tech Bank",
      "accountNumber": "1234567890",
      "swiftCode": "TECHUS123",
      "iban": "DE89370400440532013000",
      "bankAddress": "456 Bank Street, Silicon Valley, CA 94000, USA",
      "bankContactPerson": "Michael Banking"
    },
    "financialInformation": {
      "annualRevenue": 10000000.00,
      "creditLimit": 1000000.00,
      "paymentTerms": "Net 30",
      "currencyPreference": "USD"
    },
    "kycInformation": {
      "status": "Pending",
      "documents": [
        {
          "documentType": "Certificate of Incorporation",
          "documentName": "acme_incorporation.pdf",
          "documentDescription": "Certificate of Incorporation for Acme Corp",
          "documentUrl": "https://storage.example.com/documents/acme_incorporation.pdf"
        }
      ]
    },
    "uboInformation": [
      {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "ownershipPercentage": 51.00
      },
      {
        "name": "Jane Smith",
        "ownershipPercentage": 49.00
      }
    ]
  }
}




{
  "legalEntity": {
    "name": "TechVision Solutions",
    "shortName": "TechVision",
    "type": "Organization",
    "registrationNumber": "REG789012",
    "dateOfIncorporation": "2015-03-15T00:00:00",
    "country": "Canada",
    "taxIdentificationNumber": "TAX456789",
    "industryType": "Software Development",
    "contactInformation": {
      "primaryContactName": "Michael Chen",
      "primaryContactPhoneNumber": "+1 (604) 555-7890",
      "primaryContactEmail": "michael.chen@techvision.com",
      "secondaryContactName": "Sarah Johnson",
      "secondaryContactPhoneNumber": "+1 (604) 555-4321",
      "secondaryContactEmail": "sarah.johnson@techvision.com",
      "website": "https://www.techvision.com"
    },
    "addressInformation": {
      "streetAddress": "456 Innovation Drive",
      "city": "Vancouver",
      "stateProvince": "BC",
      "postalCode": "V6B 1A1",
      "country": "Canada"
    },
    "bankInformation": {
      "accountName": "TechVision Solutions Operating Account",
      "bankName": "Royal Bank of Canada",
      "accountNumber": "9876543210",
      "swiftCode": "ROYCCAT2",
      "iban": "CA34ROYC3456789012345",
      "bankAddress": "789 Financial Street, Vancouver, BC V6C 1A2, Canada",
      "bankContactPerson": "David Banking"
    },
    "financialInformation": {
      "annualRevenue": 5000000.00,
      "creditLimit": 500000.00,
      "paymentTerms": "Net 45",
      "currencyPreference": "CAD"
    },
    "kycInformation": null,
    "uboInformation": [
      {
        "name": "Michael Chen",
        "ownershipPercentage": 60.00
      },
      {
        "name": "Sarah Johnson",
        "ownershipPercentage": 40.00
      }
    ]
  }
}

Snippet
public record LegalEntityDto
{
    public required string Name { get; init; }
    public string? ShortName { get; init; }
    public required EntityType Type { get; init; }
    public string? RegistrationNumber { get; init; }
    public DateTime? DateOfIncorporation { get; init; }
    public required string Country { get; init; }
    public string? TaxIdentificationNumber { get; init; }
    public required string IndustryType { get; init; }
    public required ContactInformationDto ContactInformation { get; init; }
    public required AddressInformationDto AddressInformation { get; init; }
    public required BankInformationDto BankInformation { get; init; }
    public required FinancialInformationDto FinancialInformation { get; init; }
    public KycInformationDto? KycInformation { get; init; }
    public ICollection<UboInformationDto> UboInformation { get; init; } = new List<UboInformationDto>();

    private class Mapping : Profile
    {
        public Mapping()
        {
            CreateMap<LegalEntity, LegalEntityDto>();
            CreateMap<LegalEntityDto, LegalEntity>();
        }
    }
}

public record KycDocumentDto
{
    public required string DocumentType { get; init; }
    public required string DocumentName { get; init; }
    public string? DocumentDescription { get; init; }
    public required string DocumentUrl { get; init; }

    private class Mapping : Profile
    {
        public Mapping()
        {
            CreateMap<KycDocument, KycDocumentDto>();
            CreateMap<KycDocumentDto, KycDocument>();
        }
    }
}

public sealed record CreateLegalEntityCommand : IRequest<Result<Guid>>
{
    public required LegalEntityDto LegalEntity { get; init; }
}

public sealed class CreateLegalEntityCommandHandler(AppDbContext dbContext, IMapper mapper) : IRequestHandler<CreateLegalEntityCommand, Result<Guid>>
{
    public async Task<Result<Guid>> Handle(CreateLegalEntityCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var entity = mapper.Map<LegalEntity>(request.LegalEntity);

        dbContext.LegalEntities.Add(entity);

        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return entity.Id;
    }
}

public class CreateLegalEntityEndpoint : IEndpoint
{
    public static void MapEndpoint(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(endpoints);

        endpoints.MapPost("/legalentities",
                async (CreateLegalEntityCommand command, ISender sender, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
                {
                    var result = await sender.Send(command, cancellationToken);
                    return result.Match(id => Results.Created($"/legalentities/{id}", id), CustomResults.Problem);
                })
            .Produces<Guid>(StatusCodes.Status201Created)
            .ProducesValidationProblem()
            .ProducesProblem(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)
            .WithTags(nameof(LegalEntity))
            .WithOpenApi(operation => new OpenApiOperation(operation)
            {
                Summary = "Create a new legal entity",
                Description = "Creates a new legal entity with all its related information"
            });
    }
}


You can use IFormFileCollection to receive multiple files from the client side in your controller. This collection can then be processed to upload each document individually to Azure Blob Storage.



How do I actually upload these documents?  IFormFileCollection  in some way?
Are  DocumentType,  DocumentName,  DocumentDescription, and  DocumentUrl  enough for Azure Storage Account, or have I missed any other property that's required?


Yes, you can use IFormFileCollection to upload multiple KYC documents to an Azure Storage Account Container.
In my environment, I created sample asp.net core project and you can see the below step by step approach to upload multiple KYC documents to an Azure Storage Account Container using IFormFileCollection.
appsettings.json
{
  "AzureBlobStorage": {
    "ConnectionString": "xxxxx",
    "ContainerName": "xxx"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}

Program.cs
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Register BlobServiceClient as a singleton
builder.Services.AddSingleton(x =>
{
    var configuration = x.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    var connectionString = configuration["AzureBlobStorage:ConnectionString"];
    return new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

Models:
LegalEntity.cs
namespace KycDocumentsApi.Models
{
    public class LegalEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<KycDocument> KycDocuments { get; set; }
    }
}

KycDocument.cs
namespace KycDocumentsApi.Models
{
    public class KycDocument
    {
        public string DocumentType { get; set; }
        public string DocumentName { get; set; }
        public string DocumentDescription { get; set; }
        public string DocumentUrl { get; set; }
    }
}

LegalEntitiesController.cs
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using KycDocumentsApi.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KycDocumentsApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LegalEntitiesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly BlobServiceClient _blobServiceClient;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public LegalEntitiesController(BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _blobServiceClient = blobServiceClient;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpPost("upload-kyc-documents")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadKycDocuments([FromForm] string legalEntityName, IFormFileCollection files)
        {
            // Validate the legal entity name
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(legalEntityName))
            {
                return BadRequest("Legal entity name is required.");
            }

            // Validate files
            if (files == null || files.Count == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("No files uploaded.");
            }

            // Retrieve the container name from configuration and create container client
            var containerName = _configuration["AzureBlobStorage:ContainerName"];
            var containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            var documents = new List<KycDocument>();

            // Upload each file to Blob Storage
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Validate file properties
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient($"{legalEntityName}/{file.FileName}");
                    await using var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
                    await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, overwrite: true);

                    // Create document entry with metadata
                    var document = new KycDocument
                    {
                        DocumentType = "KYC Document",  // Adjust as needed
                        DocumentName = file.FileName,
                        DocumentDescription = "Uploaded KYC Document", // Customize as needed
                        DocumentUrl = blobClient.Uri.ToString()
                    };
                    documents.Add(document);
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest($"File {file.FileName} is empty.");
                }
            }

            // Create LegalEntity object to include uploaded documents if necessary
            var legalEntity = new LegalEntity
            {
                Name = legalEntityName,
                KycDocuments = documents
            };

            return Ok(legalEntity);
        }
    }
}

Now you can use the dotnet run to run the above code.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]  
Now listening on: http://localhost:5057  
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]  
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.  
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]  
Hosting environment: Development  
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

Now you can use the post request with http://localhost:5057/api/legalentities/upload-kyc-documents to upload the multiple files with legal name.
For example, I'm executed through echo Api to upload multiple files with DocumentType, DocumentName, DocumentDescription, and DocumentUrl  and they are sufficient to upload the property.
Post http://localhost:5057/api/legalentities/upload-kyc-documents
body:
 form-data 
 legalEntityName : TechVision Solutions(text or string) type
 files           : data.png(file)type
 files           : demo.pdf(file)type

Output:
{
    "name": "TechVision Solutions",
    "kycDocuments": [
        {
            "documentType": "KYC Document",
            "documentName": "data.png",
            "documentDescription": "Uploaded KYC Document",
            "documentUrl": "https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxx/TechVision Solutions/data.png"
        },
        {
            "documentType": "KYC Document",
            "documentName": "demo.pdf",
            "documentDescription": "Uploaded KYC Document",
            "documentUrl": "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxx/TechVision Solutions/demo.pdf"
        }
    ]
}


Portal:


Thanks for the response! In your example, you're creating List<KycDocumentDto>, but in my case, this list is populated on the frontend and passed within the payload. https://i.imgur.com/5jg4zaz.png. Here's a screenshot of the upload page: https://imgur.com/EYuhG56 - this is where users upload the documents, which are all submitted in a single request once the whole form is filled. Should this be handled as a single request, or should I separate the upload into its own endpoint?

the idea of using IFormFileCollection looks good to me. However, each file in this IFormFileCollection should include additional parameters, such as Document Type, Document Name, and Document Description. How do we achieve this?

You can keep it as a single request for simplicity. To include additional parameters, send each file with its metadata as part of a model (like KycDocumentDto), or pass files in IFormFileCollection and metadata as a JSON array alongside it

How do I map each document in documents to its corresponding file in the IFormFileCollection?  "documents": [ { "documentType": "Certificate of Incorporation", "documentName": "acme_incorporation.pdf", "documentDescription": "Certificate of Incorporation for Acme Corp" }. This is what I don't get

I tried async ([FromForm] CreateLegalEntityCommand command, ISender sender, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>; public sealed record CreateLegalEntityCommand : IRequest<Result<Guid>> {    public required IFormFileCollection Files { get; init; }     public required LegalEntityDto LegalEntity { get; init; } } but it fails with BadHttpRequestException: Missing required value for property 'LegalEntity'.

To handle the upload of multiple KYC documents for a legal entity to Azure Blob Storage in your ASP.NET Core project, here’s a detailed approach addressing each part of your setup.
1. Uploading Documents Using IFormFileCollection
You can use IFormFileCollection in your API endpoint to receive multiple files from the client, and then upload each file to Azure Blob Storage.
Here’s how you could set it up in a controller:
[HttpPost("uploadKycDocuments")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadKycDocuments(IFormFileCollection files, [FromBody] LegalEntityDto legalEntity)
{
    if (files == null || !files.Any())
    {
        return BadRequest("No files uploaded.");
    }

    var uploadedDocuments = new List<KycDocumentDto>();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var documentUrl = await UploadToAzureBlobAsync(file);
        
        var documentDto = new KycDocumentDto
        {
            DocumentType = "Specify type", // Populate with document type
            DocumentName = file.FileName,
            DocumentDescription = "Specify description", // Populate with document description
            DocumentUrl = documentUrl
        };
        
        uploadedDocuments.Add(documentDto);
    }

    // Attach uploaded document details to the legal entity's KYC information
    legalEntity.KycInformation = new KycInformationDto
    {
        Status = "Pending",
        Documents = uploadedDocuments
    };

    // Continue processing the legal entity or store in the database
    // ...

    return Ok(uploadedDocuments);
}

2. Upload Method to Azure Blob Storage
This method uploads a single IFormFile to Azure Blob Storage and returns the file URL. You’ll need to configure the Azure Blob Service client for this:
private async Task<string> UploadToAzureBlobAsync(IFormFile file)
{
    var blobContainerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("your-container-name");
    var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);

    using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
    {
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, overwrite: true);
    }

    return blobClient.Uri.ToString(); // This URL can be stored as DocumentUrl
}

3. Metadata Structure for KYC Document Storage
Your payload structure appears to be comprehensive for document metadata, and it includes all essential fields:

DocumentType: Describes the type of document, e.g., "Certificate of Incorporation."
DocumentName: The original or customized name of the document file.
DocumentDescription: Optional, but helpful for further context.
DocumentUrl: URL for accessing the document in Azure Blob Storage.

These fields are generally enough for KYC document handling. Azure Blob Storage does allow adding custom metadata properties if needed, though storing detailed metadata like document type or description is usually better in a database for easier querying.
4. Using DTOs and Entity Mapping
In your provided setup, you’re already using DTOs and a CreateLegalEntityCommand for handling the business logic. After uploading files and obtaining their URLs, you could map the LegalEntityDto with populated KycInformation back to your entity model and save it to your database.
5. Example of Complete Legal Entity Command with Documents
When creating the legal entity with CreateLegalEntityCommand, ensure that the KycInformation (with the uploaded document URLs) is fully populated in the command handler before saving it to the database.

I wanna know if it's possible to upload file to my minimal API endpoint, not a controller action https://pastebin.com/BYE0ECmm

https://i.imgur.com/EYuhG56.png this is the page in question. Perhaps, the upload should be separated into a different endpoint?
